# Gauss addition formula

Tags: arithmetic

I have programmed a simple pythonic version of Gauss addition. It came up when watching a YouTube video of a story from when he was a child. The formula $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \ldots$ that I came across seemed overly complex. I like to think I can recognize patterns so I spent a minute thinking about it and came up with this:

```
user = int(input('Number: '))
num = user
mult = num * num
result = (mult + num) / 2
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Number: 100
5050.0

Number: 14
105.0

Number: 123456789
7620789436823655.0
```

After testing this I find the results are the same and it computes easier than $$\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}.$$ So my question is why is it equated as $n(n + 1)$ when it's easier to calculate $$\frac{(n \times n) + n}{2} ?$$

Comment: $n(n+1)=n^2+n$....if you prefer the latter, you can certainly use it.

Comment: I do thank you :) ive amended it to `mult = n ** 2`

Comment: Please explain:  "computes easier than $n(n+1)/2$".

Comment: polynomial time is shorter according to the syntax. I suspect it is the way that the binary operates. It is quicker to square and add than recognize parenthesis without square and compute

Comment: You could never sense the difference in performance time. Compilers usually takes care of any possible optimizations like this. Never worry about this, worry about precision and programming accuracy.

Comment: I would say there is always a performance time. Without going into P vs NP it reduces to Boolean. No matter the difference in time, the notion there is a time difference is proof of one easier than the other

Comment: Have you benchmarked this?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same amount of computation:
one add, one multiply,
one divide by two.

When you are working
with expressions like this,
if you can write it
in factored form
(i.e., n(n+1)),
it can often be combined
with other expressions
that occur in the computation
more readily.

However,
you have to be alert
for the need to use
the distributive law
in various ways
to combine or split
expressions.

Comment: It takes the computer less time to compute a square than read a parenthesis without a square

Comment: But it might take more time to add n than to add 1 to n. You would have to take a look at the actual assembly code to see what really happens.

Comment: Run the code both ways. You see a result of how long each one took to compute

Comment: Okay? I was just explaining that clearly that is the definition of easier..less time..less stress... You cared enough to provide an answer which I thank you for but there really is no need for being so dismissive to the proof